# MASM segment directive

Tags: assembly, masm

I am reading some assembly for MASM and I have trouble understanding the purpose of segment directive. How is it different from labels in address computation during the assembly? Assume the form directive as just `name segment at addr`, I dont much care for those other options it has. What is

```
BootSeg segment at 0x7c0
BootSeg end
```

good for if it has nothing within?

What value would you have in ax if you did:

```
mov ax, BootSeg
```

?

Comment: That's a memory addressing matter, specifically the real-mode addressing. I'd suggest you learn more about it from Intel's Developer Manuals or from Wikipedia. Or check this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439241/finding-physical-address-in-8086-microprocessor

Comment: @Jay I know what segment registers are and how they work. I dont understand how could possibly assembler ensure those registers are loaded with what it says in this directive

Comment: It doesn't. It only tells the compiler that anything inside that segment block is at that specific memory segment so that any code *outside* that segment block can correctly reference it with e.g: `mov ax, BootSeg`. The explicit segment address (along with the `ORG` directive) is usually used for Interrupt Vector Table, BIOS Data Area, Video Memory, etc. where actual data isn't supplied from the binary. It's like a data structure template that is fixed to a specific memory segment.

Comment: @Jay That kinda sounds like label to me. Is that correct assumption? Except if you do void segment declaration it serves as "label equ address". Right? Also what is the final value in the ax from above? is it 7c00h or 7c0h?

Comment: Yes, it's similar like label. But `EQU` is for constant declaration and it's not for label only. The `ax` register would be `07C0h` as specified on the `SEGMENT AT` directive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `segment` directive is sort of multipurpose.

The first use is to combine things into segments.

The second use is to refer to (= calculate address of) objects in various segments properly. Depending on the segment of an object being accessed in your code, the assembler can insert appropriate `segment override prefixes` (`es:`, `ss:`, `cs:`, `fs:`, `gs:`) into the generated code. Likewise when calling a `procedure` from a different code segment, the assembler can generate the `far call` instruction instead of the `near call`. AFAIR, for that you actually need to mark the `procedure` itself as `far` (and that will turn all plain `rets` into `far rets` in the routine as well).

The segments are then taken care of by the linker and turned into relocation information that's consumed by the OS.

Why do we have these segments? Because the CPU has them and we can't always ignore their existence. There are DOS .COM programs that fit their code, data and stack into a single segment, in which case the program does not have to be complicated by the notion of segments (except those cases when it needs to access some "foreign" code/data, not from its own segment).

And yes, the `AT` thing basically overlays one object on top of the other. So `mov ax, BootSeg` should get you `ax` = 0x7c0 just as with any other segment, except here the segment is known at "compile" time.

Use a debugger, experiment.